# How do I make CD+Gs from MP4s?

Tags: compact-disc, karaoke

I am trying to find an easy way to convert my MP4 files into a [CD+G disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD%2BG) so that I can use them with my karaoke machine.

Is there any method I can use to convert multiple MP4s into a CD+G?

Comment: [Quick Google search found this](http://power-cdg-burner.power-karaoke.softalizer.com/)

Comment: What OS are you using and did Moab's comment help you?

Answer (score 0):

A CD+G file is short for **C**ompact **D**isk + Graphics file. Essentially, you can play a regular CD in a karaoke player.
If you are asking how to make a CD+G format file from an MP4 file, it isn’t quite so simple. You need specific karaoke CD+G authoring software to do it. [Karaoke CD+G Creator Pro](http://www.powerkaraoke.com/src/prod_karaokecdgcreatorpro.php) is a program that comes to mind.

Here’s the thing, whenever you create a karaoke disk from artist you like, it is imperative you do not take it outside of your home unless you have express permission from the artist to make that karaoke CD and use it anywhere you go for karaoke.

Now, about Karaoke CD+G Creator. It has the ability to (somewhat decently) remove vocals from an MP4 file, in addition to walk you through creating the lyric sheet and timers for the song.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t want to say this is impossible but I think you will have great difficulty not in the conversion to CD+G format (as I’m sure that would be possible) but in finding an optical disc burner that will burn the CD+G format.

I was asked by a friend if I could make backups of CD+G discs many years ago, after looking onto to it for him it turned out 99% of optical disc burners didn’t support the format.

I spent many an hour trying to find sites that listed drives that could burn the format but the drive where very rare and expensive. And with the demise of the optical drive these days I fear you’ll find it equally difficult.

So I took a different approach at the problem and came up with this.
It’s easier to mix the audio from your MP4 player and your karaoke amp.

For me this was a original xBox with XBMC installed and a simple DJs mixer into my audio system.

These days I’d probably swap the xBox for a low cost Android box or Raspberry Pi to run XBMC/Kodi and have all your MP4s on an SD card and never have to swap karaoke discs again.